# Стрелка в input

Tags: html, css, html5

Как в поле input добавить вот такую стрелку.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как по мне это элемент другого <input type="submit" /> как появляющаяся лупа на этом сайте http://prntscr.com/fyeql6

Comment: возможно а как это сделать что бы стрелка была в <input type="email">

Answer (score 3):

https://jsfiddle.net/Lot5nd65/

Реализуйте через абсолютное позиционирование

```
input {
  width: 90%;
}
.input-group-btn {
  position: relative;
}
button {
   position: absolute;
   left: -30px;
   top: 1px;
   background: #fff;
   border: none;
}
```

Comment: как по мне так пример , как бы не завершённый , при focus он должен и обязан пропадать ... хотя сделано верно

Comment: Где-то был запрос про то, что стрелку нужно прятать?